# Creating an ambiguous test

Tags: c#, boolean, var

I had an idea about creating a bool `isNull` that can be used pretty much ambiguously wherever needed. The original idea was as follows (pseudo-code only):

```
bool isNull(var test)
{
    if (test == null || DBNull || string.Empty)
                 return true;
    else
                 return false;
}
```

But this doesn't work, as `var` is not recognised here. Instead, it appears to be assumed that `var` refers to a type... well I, of course, don't have a type for `var`!

What do I do to get around this? Or, perhaps the question I *should* be asking, Is this a good idea at all?

Comment: You just need to turn your `var` into an `object` to make it work. Don't know if this is a good idea though, it all depends on how you plann to use it.

Comment: @ppetrov The idea is to use it anywhere I need to check for `null`. In effect, it replaces doing a test *each time* I have to do this.

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use object ?

```
bool isNull(object test)
{
    if (test == null || test == DBNull.Value)
         return true;
    else
         return false;
}
```

For `strings`, I would use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method.For other types, especially when you are dealing with databases this function can be useful.

Comment: I like this. I like it a lot. Also, why are you repeating `test ==` each time? Is is just utter redundancy?

Comment: Because it's how C# syntax works (as well as a lot other languages). Each part between boolean operators have to return a boolean.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, I'm an idiot. For reference, I was putting `String.IsNullOrEmpty` in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because `var` will be resolved at compile-time.

You could use `object` or `dynamic` as type. `dynamic` will be resolved at run-time

Comment: Are you sure thats the case with `var`? If so, how is it correctly attributed when I use it inside a method?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If you use it inside a method like `var value = "Hello World"`, then it gets the Type by the type right of the `=`